# Importing the file 'xxx.targets' results in a circular dependency

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I have a NuGet package called "Contoso.Library" with a targets file: "/build/Contoso.Library.targets"

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, when I try and build a project containing this I get the following error:

> Importing the file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" into the file "C:\Users\rb.nuget\packages\contoso.library\1.0.0\build\contoso.library.targets" results in a circular dependency.  C:\Users\rb.nuget\packages\contoso.library\1.0.0\build\contoso.library.targets

[image]

I have confirmed that if I rename the targets file to "contoso.library.targets.xxx" this error goes away, demonstrating that the targets file is where the problem lies.

For reference, here is the project file of the project consuming Contoso.Library:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Library" Version="1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the answer is actually really simple - just drop the "Sdk" attribute from the Project element in the targets file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

becomes

```
<Project>
```

Comment: It is the `Sdk` attribute that determines whether to use the new `.csproj` format or the old`.csproj` format. All this does is switch you back to using the old `.csproj` format (whether that is a good or bad thing depends on the specific case). Personally, I would try to find a way to do it without switching back to the old `.csproj` format.

Comment: But the “Sdk” attribute will still be set in the csproj file, so I will still be using the new format, right?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that you were doing this in the main project not in the targets file. Then yes, removing this is the right solution.

Comment: It's mad that I ended up here on SO for a solution to my problem as nowhere in the MS docs does it provide this little nugget of info. +1 officially as that's all I can give you. +1,000 unofficially for saving me pulling the last few strands of hair from my head! :)

Answer (score 0):

The same error and the same solution (thanks @RB. !), but I was using `Directory.Build.props` file instead of a targets file.

My error:

> Importing the file "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" into
> the file "<*snip*>\Directory.Build.props" results in a circular
> dependency

Exact solution:
I removed the `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` attribute from the `Directory.Build.props` and the projects rebuild correctly.

HTH!